# Adding a URL to the end of a specific line inside a file

Tags: bash, awk

My script takes an input file like this

```
user:tag:count
```

It takes the user, searches it on a page, and outputs the URL pointing the user. After this is done the input file should be changed to

```
user:tag:count:URL
```

The script is a while loop that starts at i=line1 and ends at the last line.
So the line the loop is working on is stored in $i and the URL it got is stored in $url.

Normally i would to this with sed but i experienced problems with that if the variable contains "/". I tried it with awk:

```
    awk -v iv="$i" 'NR == iv' input | awk -v var="$count" '{print $0 ":"var}'
```

It adds the URL at the right line, but ofc it wont help with editing input file in the way i want.

Any way to merge the 2 awk's into one so i can edit the file?

Comment: you can use a delimiter that won't be found in variable... for ex: `#` or `|`... `echo 'foo bar' | sed 's#foo#baz#'`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sed` with a non-`/` delimiter. For example:

```
sed 's|foo|bar|'
```

But yes, you can also join the two awk commands:

```
awk -v iv="$i" -v var="$count" 'NR == iv{print $0 ":"var}'
```